Python3 stripping last binary chars
There is a byte stream from socket and it comes likes this

b"8=FIXT.1.1\x019=000076\x0135=A\x0149=ABCD\x0156=0109\x01"

I need to strip the last \x01 (or \\x01)
So here is the sample python script to demo my requirement
#!/usr/bin/python
test=b"8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01"
print(test)
data=str(test)
data=data.rstrip("\\x01")
print(data)

It needs to print. like this after striping the last bytes
b'8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01'
b'8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109

but it prints like this without stripping
b'8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01'
b'8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01'

How to do that in python3 ?

why did you do data=str(test)? don't do that. you converted your bytes object to a str representation of a bytes object, which makes no sense. but consequently, you are adding the characters "'" to the str, so rstrip won't find "\x01"` to strip

The last characters in data are literally \x01', it's not a single byte with the value 1 which you seem to expect. Keep binary data as raw binary data, not as string.

When calling str(data) the "b" and single quotes are included in the resulting string, so your string ends with a quote, not with "\x01".
Use the encode method.
Secondly, rstrip will interpret the argument as individual characters, not a suffix. So if you string would end with "0101010101xxxxx", these would all be stripped by it. You could use endswith instead:
For instance,
test = b"8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01"
data = test.decode('ascii')
if data.endswith("\\x01"):
    data = data[:-4]
print(data)

With Python 3.9+ you can use removesuffix:
test = b"8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01"
data = test.decode('ascii')
data = data.removesuffix("\\x01")
print(data)

Finally, if you really wanted to have a sequence of bytes as result (and not a string), then just skip the string conversion and use bytes as argument for the removesuffix call:
data = b"8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01"
data = data.removesuffix(b"\\x01")
print(data)


upvoted, but it is unclear if the OP should be converting to a str to begin with, certainly if that is the case, then the OP should know that encoding

also, since Python 3.9 they added (finally) a removesuffix method (and removeprefix) which should be used here

Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga. Added the removesuffix version.

Thanks @trincot ... your last solution with removesuffix is the one suits me and works

You can strip from bytes too. I would first strip from bytes, then convert to string.
In [1]: test=b"8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109\\x01"
In [2]: test.rstrip(b"\\x01")
Out[2]: b'8=FIXT.1.1\\x019=000076\\x0135=A\\x0149=ABCD\\x0156=0109'

